# Can MapsterMapper/Mapster automatic updates DTO when entity changed?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, object-object-mapping, mapster

[MapsterMapper/Mapster](https://github.com/MapsterMapper/Mapster)

MapsterMapper/Mapster 7.3.0

EFCore 7.0.5

asp.net core 7.0.0

Entity Class

```cs
public class Setting
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id {get;set;}

    public string Name {get;set;}

    public string Value {get;set;}
}
```

Dto Class

```cs
public class SettingDto
{    
    public Guid Id {get;set;}
    
    [Required]
    public string Name {get;set;}

    [Required]
    public string Value {get;set;}
}
```

Code

```cs
var dtoToAdd = new SettingDto
    {
        Name = "setting1",
        Value = "value1"
    };

var entity = dtoToAdd.Adapt<Setting>();
//change the setting name
entity.Name = "entitySetting1";
DbContext.Entity<Setting>().Add(entity);
DbContext.SaveChanges();

//Assert that dtoToAdd will automatic updated
Assert.Equal(entity.Name, dtoToAdd.Name);
Assert.Equal(entity.Id, dtoToAdd.Id);
```

When `entity` is changed, is there any way to make `dtoToAdd` automatically update to the latest value of the entity? Can Mapster do it? My asp.net core controllers don't know `Setting` but know `SettingDto`.

Comment: Aautomatically? No. Manually? Yes. Just map back from entity to dto.

Comment: It can't update automatically with the destination object in Mapster